# custom plugin not working at all

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-effects

I'm trying to apply a custom plugin to some `div`. Here is the code :

```
$.fn.popout = function( options ){

    var settings = $.extend({
        l : this.width()/2,
        h : this.height()/2,
        percent: 100,  //default 100
        speed : 800, //default 800 
        easing : 'easeOutBounce'    //default easeOutBounce
    },options);


    return this.effect(
            'scale',
            {origin:['middle','center'], 
            from:{width: settings.l, height: settings.h},
            percent: settings.percent,
            direction: 'both',
            easing: settings.easing}, settings.speed);
};
```

As you can see, it applies a sort of "pop-out" effect to a `$('.someclass')` div. The problem is that if I apply the `effect` in this way :

```
$('.someclass').effect('scale', .. code )
```

It works perfectly, instead if I use

```
$('.someclass').popout({..options..})
```

When the script runs , the `scaled` element does not reach it's `100%` value , but it stucks at `from` dimensions.

Suggestions?

I wrote the plugin because I have to apply it to several divs in different moments of my script.

Comment: this.width() will only give you the width of the first selected element, that part should be inside the .each

Comment: I tried also to set the dimensions through options , the result is always the same.